# Why is Thunderbird Mail erratic after upgrading to 21.10?

Tags: email, thunderbird, 21.10

After sorting out account configuration issues very recently with Thunderbird, and having it work perfectly with 21.04, the program now is erratic when sending mail. I am unable to quit Thunderbird with either the top left menu Quit command or the keyboard chord command. Sometimes after invoking the Quit command from the Menu, nothing will happen for several seconds and then the computer will just do a restart (as if it were reading my mind). If the computer does not restart after giving a quit command, I have to manually select restart from Settings, in order for the mail program to be no longer active.

I do not mind restarting the computer when the mail program refuses to quit. I do not mind when the computer just automatically restarts after a ineffective Quit command. I do think that neither of these things is a normal way of operating Thunderbird, which has worked well for me, before 21.10.

If this is something that will be addressed by whoever it is that does these things, then I am content to just restart when the mail program locks up. Otherwise, I may need a fix.

Comment: It won't be "*addressed by whoever it is that does these things*" unless somebody files a bug report with enough detail to reproduce the problem in a test environment. Thunderbird on both of my 21.10 desktops works properly, so the problem is not universal, and might be hard (impossible?) to duplicate in a test environment. Check your syslog and journalctl for troubleshooting messages. Try reinstalling the Thunderbird deb. Try using the Thunderbird Snap instead.

Comment: user535733, I believe you, but barely understand what you are saying...my weakness, not yours. I attempted to submit a bug report, but not even able to do that, for lack of understanding. I have homework to do, sorting out the meanings of the key words and phrases in your answer,

Comment: Welcome! We were all beginners once. Your comment suggests that you are keeping an open mind, you are patient, and you are willing to have a little fun while learning. GREAT. Those are the three keys to success in Open Source software.

Comment: Question: If you logout and login again, at the Password screen you should see al little "gear" icon.  That will give you a choice to select an X session or a Wayland session. Take a few minutes and try both. Does the problem occur on just one type of session, or or does the problem occur on both types of session?

Comment: to user535733, I do not understand "select an X session or a Wayland session". Will try to look this up, tomorrow. I've encountered the terms "Thunderbird deb" and "Thunderbird Snap" and have to study that, too.

Comment: @user535733 I did as you suggested, and also as Chris Hall suggested. The xorg option seems to have remedied my situation. My thanks to all for their time and effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with 2 different computers running 21.10 (one an older laptop, the other a virtual machine on a more modern laptop). The problem seems to be related to the Wayland system that is now the default X server. If you switch to Xorg (possible in the settings symbol on the login screen), you may find that the problem disappears. I also had a lot of trouble that was not related to Thunderbird with Wayland on 21.04. I don't think Wayland is ready for prime time, at least with Ubuntu.

Comment: Grateful for your response, now I have to learn how to read your answer and understand it. (am dog-paddling in the Ubuntu kiddie pool.

Comment: Your answer worked for me.
@tom-koehler: Doing in detail: (1) log out, (2) select your username, (3) click gear icon at bottom right, (4) select "Ubuntu auf Xorg" (German version), (5) enter user's password.

Comment: The problem I observed reproduceably occurred when writing and sending one email and then a second one. Then the Thunderbird icon in the menu/taskbar (where the active applications are listed) had two dots, indicating that there are two Thunderbird windows opened (but there was only the main window). Clicking at the Thunderbird icon (for switching from another application to Thunderbird) didn't do anything (and even worse sometimes opened a noncloseable menu (with "all windows", ..., "Quit 2 Windows")). Temporary workaround was to start another Thunderbird instance via xterm or the like.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Wayland mode on Ubuntu 21.10 (kde-plasma-dekstop) for about two weeks now.

I am not using Thunderbird from apt repository but downloaded it directly from the Thunderbird web site (v91.2) and unzipped to a folder.

Afterwards I created the links to my profile folder and it works fine. There are some other minor issues with Wayland mode but not with Thunderbird.